# Upper-bound on energy of nonlinear boundary-value problem

Tags: differential-equations, inequalities, nonlinear-optimization, differential-inequalities

**The problem:**

Consider the following boundary-value problem for the function $\rho : \mathbb{R}^{+} \to  \mathbb{R}$ with boundary conditions $\lim_{x\to \infty}\rho(x) \to 1$  and $\lim_{x\to 0}\rho(x) \to \infty$:

$$\rho^{\prime \prime}-\frac{\rho^{\prime 2}}{\rho}+\frac{\rho^{\prime}}{x}+\frac{\kappa^2}{x^2 \rho}-\rho^2 f(\rho)=0
$$

where $\kappa \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant and

$$
f(\rho) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-(\rho-1)}(\rho-1)(3-\rho)
$$

Define the "energy" of the solution

$$
E = \int _0^\infty  x \left(\frac{\rho'}{\rho}\right)^2 dx
$$

**By playing around numerically, I am led to the following conjecture: $E =O(\kappa)$ for small $\kappa$**.

---

**A very quick analysis:**

- I will not attempt to prove that a solution exists, nor do I ask for such an argument. In the following I assume that a solution exists.
- The asymptotic form at small $x$ is $\rho \sim -\kappa \ln(\alpha x)$ for some constant $\alpha$. Assuming this approximate form for $x<x_I$, the energy is at least (roughly)

$$
\int_0 ^{x_I} \frac{1}{x(\ln(\alpha x))^2} = - \frac{1}{\ln(\alpha x_I)} \sim  \frac{\kappa}{\rho}
$$

- Numerically, it appears that $\rho$ is monotonically decreasing. Assuming this is true, then it follows  $\rho>1$, such that the $x<x_I$ contribution to the energy is $O(\kappa)$.
- The large $x$ asymptotic form is $\rho \sim 1+ \frac{\kappa^2}{x^2} +O(\frac{1}{x^3})$. Assuming this is valid for $x>x_O$, the large $x$ contribution to the energy is to leading order

$$
\int_{x_O} ^{\infty} x(2\kappa^2/x^3)^2 dx = \left(\frac{\kappa^2}{x_O^2}\right)^2 
$$

- Depending on when the large $x$ asymptotic form becomes valid, this contribution may be $O(1)$ (or larger) or $O(\kappa)$, though my numerics suggest this contribution is at most $O(\kappa^2)$, such that in total $E = O(\kappa)$.

---

**In summary:** is it true that $E=O(\kappa)$ for small $\kappa$? Can it at least be proven that $E=O(\kappa^n)$ for some $n>0$?

Comment: Can you provided a link to the derivation of the small-$x$ and large-$x$ asymptotics?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I have not rigorously proven that these are correct, though plugging in those forms we see that the equation is satisfied in the small-$x$ and large - $x$ limit. Perhaps someone better trained in differential equations will confirm that these are indeed correct to leading order.